# custom NavigationBar with Image background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, uinavigationbar

Need help on a Custom `NavigationBar` for my application.

1. Image which is sorter than width of screen.
2. `BackgroundColor`

UIDesign is as below

[image: UI Design for Navigation bar]

```
 UIImage *gradientImage44 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"actionbar_logobar"];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:83.0/255.0 blue:160.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Above code is repeating the background image, also background color is not visible. 
The result is:

[image]

Kindly guide me. Thanks

Comment: add the asset you are using

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a resizable image:

```
UIImage* img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"actionbar_logobar"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 50)];
```

You will need to change the values to match the stretchable part of your image though...